# Visualforce Charting Bar Series to show negative values

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I am currently testing out Visualforce Charting to see if it is worth using but I have hit an issue when using negative values in the chart. Basically, I have a Y number axis showing values between -20 and 20, and an X category axis showing various labels (in this example lets call them A, B and C).

So now when I view the chart the Y Axis shows labels from 20 at the top, down to -20.  The X Axis however starts from -20 when I would really prefer it to be drawn from 0.  Is there any way to do this?

Since I know Visualforce Charting is based upon the Ext JS library I have been reading these documents and taking a look at examples but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.  I also know about the rendererFn attribute that lets me provide a javascript function to act as an override but I can't find enough useful documentation to figure out if it will let me reposition the X Axis.

Comment: Can you post your code?